# generate Jacoco exec for androidTest

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, jacoco, gradle-plugin

I want to generate `.exec` file using Jacoco for the `androidTest` folder. For now it is generating for only the `test` folder. How can I generate it for Instrument testcases and combine the reports of both androidTest and test folders.

Any code snippet or example link?

Comment: I'd like to know the answer to this too.